# Filebeat / Logstash initial ingestion + continued workload

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am new to the ELK stack and trying to make things a bit easier, we have a few fuelphp instances which have their own app logs within them. I am trying to aggregate those logs into ELK so that they can be searched over and visualised.

I have set up a filebeat process on the server in question, and set up a separate server for logstash and elasticsearch. All seems to be working until its starts a harverster for each application log file. We currently have about 6 projects which have about a years worth of logs in this format:

```
/YYYY/MM/D.log
```

I am trying to ingest all of them to start with, but then would like to just be watching the latest, but I keep hitting `too many files open` issues, also due to the registry holding the store, when the files are closed due to inactivity, if I make an adjustment to the config and restart they all reopen again.

Here is the snippet of the filebeat.yml:

```
# List of prospectors to fetch data.
filebeat.prospectors:
# Each - is a prospector. Most options can be set at the prospector level, so
# you can use different prospectors for various configurations.
# Below are the prospector specific configurations.

# Type of the files. Based on this the way the file is read is decided.
# The different types cannot be mixed in one prospector
#
# Possible options are:
# * log: Reads every line of the log file (default)
# * stdin: Reads the standard in

#------------------------------ Log prospector --------------------------------
- input_type: log

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  # To fetch all ".log" files from a specific level of subdirectories
  # /var/log/*/*.log can be used.
  # For each file found under this path, a harvester is started.
  # Make sure not file is defined twice as this can lead to unexpected behaviour.
  paths:
    - /srv/**/production/fuel/app/logs/**/**/*.php

  # Exclude lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It drops the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list. The include_lines is called before
  # exclude_lines. By default, no lines are dropped.
  exclude_lines: ['^<\?php ']

  # Set to true to store the additional fields as top level fields instead
  # of under the "fields" sub-dictionary. In case of name conflicts with the
  # fields added by Filebeat itself, the custom fields overwrite the default
  # fields.
  fields_under_root: false

  # The regexp Pattern that has to be matched. The example pattern matches all lines starting with [
  multiline.pattern: '^[A-Z]+ - '

  # Defines if the pattern set under pattern should be negated or not. Default is false.
  multiline.negate: true

  # Match can be set to "after" or "before". It is used to define if lines should be append to a pattern
  # that was (not) matched before or after or as long as a pattern is not matched based on negate.
  # Note: After is the equivalent to previous and before is the equivalent to to next in Logstash
  multiline.match: after

  # Defines if prospectors is enabled
  enabled: true
output.logstash:
  # Boolean flag to enable or disable the output module.
  enabled: true

  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["<IP>:5044"]

  # Number of workers per Logstash host.
  worker: 4

  # Set gzip compression level.
  compression_level: 3
```

Should I be manually ingesting the older logs and setting up an ignore_older than param for ongoing entries? Sorry I am not too sure.

Many Thanks